# p:tooltip for an icon that repeats for each row inside a column in PrimeFaces 5

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip

Assuming that I have a table with rows and columns (as expected) and one of the columns holds an icon for a trash where the `<p:tooltip>` should be "Delete" and another column has an icon of a pen where the `<p:tooltip>` should be "Edit".

How should I do to make the tooltip to be displayed for each row?

```
<p:dataTable var="usuario" value="#{panelView.usuarios}"
    rendered="#{not empty panelView.usuarios}" paginator="true"
    sortBy="#{usuario.usuario}" rows="10">
    <p:column headerText="Nome">
        <h:outputText value="#{usuario.usuario}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Grupo">
        <h:outputText value="#{usuario.grupo}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Role">
        <h:outputText value="#{usuario.role}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Sistema">
        <h:outputText value="#{usuario.sistema}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Subsistema">
        <h:outputText value="#{usuario.subsistema}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:commandLink action="...">
            <h:graphicImage value="/img/bw_edit.gif" height="16px" width="16px">
            <p:tooltip id="toolTipFade" value="Editar" />
            </h:graphicImage>
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:commandLink action="...">
            <h:graphicImage value="/img/bw_trash.gif" height="16px" width="16px">
            </h:graphicImage>
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p:column>
    <h:commandLink action="...">
        <h:graphicImage value="/img/bw_edit.gif"
                        height="16px"
                        width="16px"
                        title="Editar"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

This works for me.

Regards.